# restrict selected columns in cakephp query

Tags: sql, cakephp-1.3

I want to reduce the number of fields returned by cakephp's find('all') but don't know if this is possible.

$this->Group->find('all', $params);

where $params

```
   $params = array(
        'conditions' => array(                
            'Group.featured' => 1,
            ),
        'contain' => array(
                'User',
                'Class' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Class.exp IS NOT NULL', 
                    'Class.tb <20',
                                             )
                 )
            )
    ));
```

The problem is that my Class table has many columns that i don't need and that take a long time to load, so i would line to only select 5 fields. 
Can this be done in Cakephp or am i better off writing a regular query?

something like

```
   $params = array(
        'conditions' => array(                
            'Group.featured' => 1,
            ),
        'contain' => array(
                'User',
                'Class.a',
                'Class.b', 
                'Class.exp',
                'Class.tb',
                'Class' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Class.exp IS NOT NULL', 
                    'Class.tb <20',
                                             )
                 )
            )
    ));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [`fields` parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1018/find) is for.

```
$params = array(
    ...
    'contain' => array(
        'Class' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Class.exp IS NOT NULL', 
                'Class.tb <20',
            ),
            'fields' => array('a', 'b')
        )
    )
);
```